# C# DataGridColumnStyle.Edit() cannot be invoked

Tags: c#, winforms

I have derived a class overriding `DataGridColumnStyle`
From MSDN, it said that `Edit()` is invoked by `DataGrid.onMouseClick()` if I put `DataGridColumnStyle` to the style of DataGrid I am using.

But when I make my own class, the `DataGridColumnStyle` can be constructed normally but when I make breakpoint to its `Edit()` function (also overrided). `onMouseClick()` never fire this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved and thanks for helping.
My problem is very simple. It is `DataGridTableStyle.MappingName` stuff where when it locate to wrong source then wrong output of course and thus no `DataGridColumnStyle` is added to this thus Edit() is not fired.